# TinyMCE: How do I select a node by a current selector?

Tags: javascript, jquery, tinymce, tinymce-4

Here is how I init TinyMCE:

```
tinymce.init({
    selector: '.editable',
    inline: true,
    contextmenu: false,
    setup: function (editor) {
      editor.on('blur', function (e) {
        var content = editor.getContent();
        if ( !content )
           selector.text('Enter text here...');
      });
    }
});
```

What I basically want is to use some placeholder in case a user has removed everything inside the current `.editable` element. The code above won't work, because `selector` is not defined. How do I select a current node a different way?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to place content in the editor instance when its "empty" you can just do this:

```
tinymce.init({
  selector: '.editable',
  inline: true,
  contextmenu: false,
  setup: function (editor) {
    editor.on('blur', function (e) {
      var content = editor.getContent();
      if ( !content )
         editor.setContent('<p>Enter text here...'</p>);
    });
  }
});
```

You would then need to do something in reverse when the focus returns.

There is a 3rd party plugin that does what you appear to want:

https://github.com/mohan/tinymce-placeholder

I cannot vouch for how good the code is but perhaps that plugin will solve this issue for you in its entirety.